# Performance reduced after implementing avro serialization in jms based batch framework

Tags: java, jms, avro

Background: we have a batch framework having jms based architecture. Below is a brief working of it.

We have 2 queues.one input and other is output. On input queue, we have a simple processor, which reads records from a flat file and splits the file into group of records called chunks. Further, for each chunk, it spawns a thread from a thread pool, which in turn creates a java object for each chunk. After that, each object is converted into a string and further converted into bytes and sent to input queue. At the destination side, we have mdbs waiting for the messages which further converts bytes into string amd then into java objects and starts processing chunks. After processing, results are sent to output queue which arr further processed by other consumers.

Now in order to improve performance, we introduced avro as a serialization framework. Instead of converting chunk which is a java object into a string and then into bytes, we copy the data from chunk into avro and further same is serialised. Similar way, we convert the serialised data back to chunk using avro  deserialization.

After doing thia, we observed that we were able to reduce data size of each chunk by 30%. Earlier the chunk size was 220000 bytes which got reduced to 150000 bytes. However, when we tried to measure the performance in terms of time taken by input processor to process all the chunks, it got increased. E.g. earlier 6000 records split into 60 chunks of 100 revords took 18 seconds. Now after implementing avro, it is taking 20-22 seconds.

Questions: is measuring performance in above manner the right way?

What are some other ways of measuring performance improvement in above scenario. Apparently, size of message has reduced, but i need solid data to prove the improvement.

P.s. my thought process for using time taken by input processor as a performance parameter is that if there is less amount of data to be written on queue, threads which are spawned by the processor to process each chunk will get free earlier. Here, number of threads spawned are configurable. In above measurements, 2 threads were configured in the thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

Default codec for DataFileWriter is deflate with compression level 6. However, you might want to experiment with other codecs;

- CodecFactory.bzip2Codec()
- CodecFactory.deflateCodec(9) // default compression level 6
- CodecFactory.nullCodec() // no compression
- CodecFactory.snappyCodec()
- CodecFactory.xzCodec(9)